# In Typescript, why isn't my generic abstract class finding the type parameter when I attempt to implement it?

Tags: generics, typescript, abstract-class

I have this abstract class in typescript

```
export abstract class IGenericsReferenceDataService<T> {
    GetAll<T>(types:T) {
        return types;
    };
}
```

In another file I have this class which attempts to implement the above

```
@Injectable()
export class TradeSourceServiceGenerics implements IGenericsReferenceDataService<tradeSources> {
    GetAll<T>(types:tradeSources):tradeSources {
        return types;
    }
}
```

and in the file above I have an array of objects called tradeSources as such

```
var tradeSources = [***thedata***]
```

However in the bit of code IGenericsReferenceDataService "tradeSources" is highlighted red with an error message of "Cannot find name tradesources" this is true of the other two instances of "tradeSources" this is in Webstorm, where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few things going on here. First, you can't use variable names as types. You will need to define a type that describes your data. For example, here's an interface that might describe an item in `tradeSources`:

```
interface TradeSource {
    // replace with properties that describe an item in `tradeSources`
    name: string;
}
```

Second, if you're trying to implement something then most of the time you will want to use an interface. If you want to extend behaviour or have common behaviour between classes, then use an abstract class. Third, you probably want to use the generic constraint—`T`—from the class and not define a new one on the method.

```
export interface IGenericsReferenceDataService<T> {
    GetAll(types: T[]): T[]; 
}
```

Now you can implement this interface and use the type for an item in `tradeSources`:

```
export class TradeSourceServiceGenerics implements IGenericsReferenceDataService<TradeSource> {
    GetAll(types: TradeSource[]) {
        return types;
    }
}

var tradeSources: TradeSource[] = [{ name: "Toronto" }, { name: "New York" }];
new TradeSourceServiceGenerics().GetAll(tradeSources); // valid
```

---

Note... if you want all the classes to share some behaviour then use this code:

```
export abstract class BaseDataService<T> {
    GetAll(types: T[]) {
        return types;
    }
}

export class TradeSourceServiceGenerics extends BaseDataService<TradeSource> {
}
```

Comment: "Note... if you want all the classes to share some behaviour then use this code:" ...*Exactly* what I was looking for!